# Do any items in List<string> contain part of a separate string

Tags: c#, .net, string, linq

Let's say I have `List<string>` that looks like this:

- Apple
- Pear
- Peach
- Plum

Then in a single string, if I have:

```
I would like to eat a pear today
```

(Ignore case.) In that case I I would want `true` because `pear`is found both in the list and in the string.  But if I had a string:

```
I would like to eat a strawberry today
```

Then I would get `false` because none of the `List<string>'s` are found in the sentence.

I've been playing around with various things like:

```
string result = Fruits.FirstOrDefault(s => s.IndexOf(sentence) > 0);
```

Where `Fruits` is the `List<string>` and `sentence` is the other string.  Not nailing it.

Comment: So, if you want to have ```true\false``` as result, you can use it like ```string result = Fruits.Any(s => s.IndexOf(sentence) > 0);```

Comment: bool result = ....?  I'll give that a shot.

Comment: I always get 'false' :-(

Comment: you need to check in this way => ```string result = Fruits.Any(s => sentence.IndexOf(s) > -1);```

Comment: @tym32167, that works!  Wanna put it in an answer?

Comment: sure, added as answer

Comment: if it wasn't clear, the issue was that you were checking if the word contains the sentence instead of if the sentence contains the word.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you need to check in this way =>

`string result = Fruits.Any(s => sentence.IndexOf(s) > -1);`

or

`string result = Fruits.Any(s => sentence.Contains(s));`

Comment: `Any` returns a `bool` not a `string`.

Comment: @Aominè OP wanted to get bool as understand from question ```I would want true``` or ```Then I would get false```

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

```
bool result = Fruits.Any(s => sentence.ToLower().Contains(s.ToLower()));
```

or

```
bool result = Fruits.Any(s => sentence.IndexOf(s, StringComparison.CurrentCultureIgnoreCase) >= 0);
```

Comment: hmm, I thought this looked good, but I'm getting, "string does not contain a definition for "contains" "

Answer (score 1):

If you are open to another approach it could be done using the following method:

```
public static bool ListItemInString(List<string> listOfStrings, string stringToCheck) {
    foreach(string str in listOfStrings) {
        if (stringToCheck.ToUpper().Contains(str.ToUpper())) {
            // return true if any of the list items are found in stringToCheck
            return true;
        }
    }
    // if the method has not returned true by this point then we return false
    // to indicate none of the list items were found within the string
    return false;
}
```

This method loops through your list and checks each item against your designated string. It will return try if at any point in the foreach loop it finds that one of your list items is contained within the string, otherwise it will return false. It also takes in consideration your non-case sensitive request by converting both strings to uppercase before performing its search through the string.

**Edit**: I understand this is more of a manual approach. The previous answers on this post could similarly be worked into a method to improve code readability if this is an operation being performed multiple times.

Comment: you can use ```string.Compare``` overload to specify ```ignoreCase``` parameter as ```true``` or move this setting to function parameters. But why you think that changing 1 line of code to 5 lines and encapsulate those 5 lines into new function will improve readability? What is not understandable here ```string result = Fruits.Any(s => sentence.Contains(s));``` that you want to have function with comments for it?

Answer (score 1):

As per the initial question, if you are looking for matching strings in the sentence and not boolean result following code should help:

```
List<string> Fruits = new List<string> { "Apple", "Pear", "Peach", "Plum" };
var sentence = "I would like to eat a pear and apple today";
var sentenceLower = sentence.ToLower(); 
var delimiter = ",";
var match = Fruits
  .Where(s => sentenceLower.Contains(s.ToLower()))
  .Aggregate((i, j) => i + delimiter + j);
```

Comment: It would be better for performance to prepare sentence.ToLower() before linq query to not calculate it each time. Or use ```string.Compare``` overload and specify ```ignoreCase``` parameter as ```true```  No much impact, just as suggestion